# Shared GPU Memory. Can I turn off this feature?

Tags: windows-10, memory, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, virtual-memory

I am running:

- Windows 10
- Nvidia GTX1070-8GB
- 24GB System RAM
- i7

[image: windows10]

I am running into an issue in my video editor, complaining about depleting the GPU memory.

When inspecting my resources, I noted that Windows allocated "shared GPU memory" to my card.

In my case, 12GB is added to "total" my reported GPU memory to 20GB. (8GB Nvidia + 12gb Shared)

[image: task manager screenshot]

For the life of me, I can't find any setting to change this. Not in the Nvidia driver app, not in windows and not in the BIOS.

Does anyone know how to turn off this feature? I suspect it may be influencing my app complaining about video memory, as when it crashes and reports the GPU out of memory error, task manager shows physical GPU memory at under 6GB (of 8gb total).

How the heck do I get rid of this "shared GPU memory" so I can test my theory?

This is what my resources look like while my video editor is doing its thing... Windows is definitely allocating and using "shared video memory"

My actual error details:

**App: Davinci Resolve Studio 16.2**

[image: davinci error]

**Debug Log:**

> [0x000019c0] | GPUManager           | INFO  | 2020-04-28 20:34:00,244
>   | Flushing GPU memory...
>
> [0x000019c0] | DVIP                 | ERROR | 2020-04-28 20:34:00,815
>   | cudaMallocArray failed: Requested size 126.6 MiB (7680x4320-1
>   datatypesize 4)
>
> [0x000019c0] | DVIP                 | ERROR | 2020-04-28 20:34:00,815
>   | DeviceResourceTypeCUDA.cpp:177: CUDA error cudaErrorMemoryAllocation
>   (2)
>
> [0x000019c0] | DVIP                 | ERROR | 2020-04-28 20:34:00,816
>   | Cuda Memory Status : free 62.0 MiB total 8192.0 MiB
>
> [0x000019c0] | DVIP                 | ERROR | 2020-04-28 20:34:00,822
>   | cudaMallocArray failed: Requested size 126.6 MiB (7680x4320-1
>   datatypesize 4)
>
> [0x000019c0] | DVIP                 | ERROR | 2020-04-28 20:34:00,822
>   | DeviceResourceTypeCUDA.cpp:177: CUDA error cudaErrorMemoryAllocation
>   (2)
>
> [0x000019c0] | DVIP                 | ERROR | 2020-04-28 20:34:00,822
>   | Cuda Memory Status : free 62.0 MiB total 8192.0 MiB
>
> [0x000019c0] | GPUManager           | ERROR | 2020-04-28 20:34:00,828
>   | Exception caught while running GPU algorithms:
>
> [0x000019c0] | DVIP                 | ERROR | 2020-04-28 20:34:00,828
>   |  DVIP Exception: Position DeviceResourceTypeCUDA.cpp:177
>    - API: CUDA
>    - API Error Code: cudaErrorMemoryAllocation (2)

**Related issues from other people.**
[Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHFX_enZA734ZA734&sxsrf=ALeKk01BGS5JkUbdkGrWKS-EZkGRTPMwQQ%3A1588098919393&ei=Z3eoXrDKF6HzxgPN9Lz4AQ&q=davinci%20resolve%20your%20gpu%20memory%20is%20full%20try%20reducing%20the%20timeline%20resolution%20or%20the%20number%20of%20correctors&oq=davinci%20resolve%20your%20gpu%20memory%20is%20full%20try%20reducing%20the%20timeline%20resolution%20or%20the%20number%20of%20correctors&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQRzIECAAQR1DBVVjUamC1bGgAcAJ4AIABhwWIAcsZkgEHMy0zLjEuM5gBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjwmdW_4YvpAhWhuXEKHU06Dx8Q4dUDCAw&uact=5)

**My Resources when the App runs.**
**Sometimes my Shared video memory is utilized more than my physical video memory. 2nd pic**

[image: Resources]
[image]

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running exactly?  Please provide the full build number when you edit your question.

Comment: Done, in original question

Comment: That only works on AGP.
anyway as stated above, that memory is only used if the video memory becomes full.

There are registry hacks to do it, but its not likely your problem comes from there.

The RAM memory is only used if the graphics cards GDDR becomes too full.

Comment: What you have discovered isn't new behavior, 1809 displays the same information for the GPU, so disabling shared GPU memory won't fix your problem.  If you give us the exact error message you have received, we might be able to solve, the actual problem you are experiencing.

Comment: @Ramhound I have logged a ticket with the software's support desk. The internet is riddled with people trying to solve the same problem that I have. And none of the suggested fixes actually fixes the problem.

I am updating the question.

Comment: @LouisvanTonder - Enable CUDA hardware acceleration within DaVinci Resolve 16 settings.  This error has nothing to do with the amount of combined video memory your system has.

Comment: @Ramhound, that is the 1st thing I've done. My issue only (mostly) peaks its head out when working on a 4K timeline.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that normally. There may be some hacks specific to your video card, like editing the registry, however its not recommended. The RAM memory is only used if the graphics cards GDDR becomes too full.

Its not likely that your problem comes from the shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from the registry as this is not a Windows issue (I found this out after using dual boot with Debian), however, you CAN do it from the BIOS.

Advanced > Video Configuration Menu > Onboard Video Memory Size
Here you can modify or even disable shared memory.

Comment: This is not the same thing, unfortunately. That is dedicating some of your main memory to your onboard card as video memory. My issue is something different.

Comment: This is not a BIOS thing. After hours of struggling I booted into Kubuntu and there everything was fine. My problem is that it consumes 16 GB of the 32 GB RAM which is unacceptable, since I rarely even use the full 4 GB of the dedicated Nvidia which comes in addition to the Intel iGPU. Windows 11 locks up 16 GB RAM for nothing I will ever use.