# Reseting Shared GPU memory

Tags: memory, gpu, reset, sharing

I have been using my pc without problems for months. After installing Cyberpunk2077 running at low fps i modded one game file, that should improve fps. The value I changed is GPU RAM amount and system shared ram for GPU. Game run better. This changed default shared GPU memory. I change it to 32GB for shared and 8DB for dedicated GPU.

The file i modded: https://www.dailyesports.gg/how-to-instantly-boost-your-framerate-by-10-20-in-cyberpunk-2077-on-pc/

**The issue.**

Pc now thinks that GPU has 40 GB of RAM (8GB dedicated 32 GB shared), which (my guess) after filling dedicated RAM fills up also shared RAM. Shared RAM is slower so gpu performance drops even on windows desktop. And because system or gpu thinks, it has a lot of ram, it doesnt clear cashed data and I get some cases, when gpu ram is not full but system still uses small amount of shared ram (6GB gpu, around 900MB shared). So system is sluggish when gpu is waiting on slow ram. How can I revert this setting defining as default value 32GB of shared ram? If system would use only gpu ram and clear cache more ofthen, system would run smooth again.

[image: Using just gpu ram]
[image: Using shared without filling gpu]

I reversed the modded file to default value and run the game with adminastrator rights, nothing changed.

My search leaded to settings in BIOS which i don't have since i have desktop without option of integrated gpu. Other option suggested changing registry entries, one relevant for intel cpu (not my case) and other gpu (didnt find entry of my manufacturer).

I tried updating graphics driver with no change.

I would like to avoid resetting/reinstalling windows as I'm in the middle of project and reinstalling some softwares and pipelines is risky at this stage and could cause a halt in the project.

Hardware:
CPU: AMD Threadripper 1920x 12c/24t (no integrated gpu)
GPU: MSI AMD RX580 8GB
RAM: 64GB kingston (4x16GB sticks)
OS:WIN 10 Pro Version 1909(OS Build 18363.1440)

There is similar thread:
[Shared GPU Memory. Can I turn off this feature?](https://superuser.com/questions/1546634/shared-gpu-memory-can-i-turn-off-this-feature)

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Have you tried simply rebooting Windows?

Comment: A game file shouldn’t be able to change the amount of shared video memory Windows can detect.  How this hack even works, is very confusing.  All your doing is apparently reserving some of your virtual memory for the game.  How the values changed within Windows is very confusing.  Shared memory cannot be disabled on any version of Windows

Comment: I am so glad you said that @Ramhound .. I second the notion.. I was like ".. whaat? " .. this makes no sense to me.

Comment: Yes, I rebooted windows multiple times. No effect. The fact, that the game did something impossible in windows is rather alarming. There is no other software or setting changed in that time that could cause this (to my notice). So simple answer is, that it cant be done. Yet it happened. The only solution so far is finishing the project and then wiping windows and reinstalling (Already overdue).